# How to run laravel without using port in url?

Tags: laravel-5.1

How can I run laravel application without using port or without using the php serve command ? just like other php webapps. ex:http://localhost/myproject/

Is it possible or laravel should use the php serve command ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it on default port 80 not to laravel`s default port 8080 so you need to do this

```
php artisan serve --port=80
```